# JavaScript: Copying text to clipboard without formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got the following function in my JS code.

```
function copyEmail() {
const range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(document.getElementById('output'));
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
document.execCommand('copy');
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

When the text is copied, it also copies the formatting with it, which is a bit annoying for my current use case. Is it possible to copy the text without CSS/formatting?
I'm ok with the solution being a hack, as it's for an internal tool at my company and it does not have to be clean.

EDIT:
After a suggestion from @Kinglish, I've tried to create a new element, copy the content there and copy from there, but it throws an error.

Updated code:

```
function copyEmail() {
const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
tempDiv.setAttribute('id', 'output_hidden');
tempDiv.innerText = document.getElementById('output').innerText;
const range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(tempDiv);
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
document.execCommand('copy');
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

Error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'selectNode' on 'Range': the given Node has no parent.

I think I understand the error, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: While it doesn't directly help you, you should be able to use Ctrl+Shift+V to paste without formatting. I've found this very helpful when copying text from webpages into an email!

Comment: Yup, I know that and it's exactly about copying text into an email, but not everyone from my company knows about it and I'd prefer to make it cleaner.

Comment: I would suggest "educate your users to improve productivity" but I realise how unrealistic that sounds!

Comment: You could create a html element (don't need to actually add it to the page), stick the text in there and then grab it again with `innerText` - that would remove formatting

Comment: @Kinglish
I've tried to do it your way, but it returns an error. I will update the main post in a second and I will be grateful if you were able to take a look at it.

Comment: @AleksanderGrzegorzewski - so the origin of the copy text is a HTML element or a form (input) element?

Comment: @Kinglish The copyEmail function is called from a .js file, by a button with an onClick attribute.